# Best practices for RESTFUL routes URL for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

For Rails application for JSON requests I see that out of the box it defaults to url appended with .json endpoint in the URL.

This is true when I specify `respond_to :json` in the controller and use `respond_with` in the action.

Wouldn't it make more sense if I do a post request it should not include .json in the URL?

Is there any Rails way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define defaults on routes.
For example:

```
resources :articles, defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

Or even better if you have namespace then you don't have to specify it for every route:

```
namespace :v1, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  resources :articles
  resources :users
  ...
end
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults